# What should be put into this fragment viewmodel?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, model-view-controller

I want to ask about fragment and viewmodel. I'm making a gridView that can display images with retrofit (navigation drawer). When using mainActivity, there are no problems, but when using fragments, there is an error like below.

```
public class InfografisFragment extends Fragment {

private InfografisViewModel infografisViewModel;
private List<Spacecraft> spacecraftList;

private GridViewAdapter adapter;
private GridView gridView;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    infografisViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InfografisViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_infografis, container, false);

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    MyAPIService myAPIService = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(MyAPIService.class);
    gridView = getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    Call<List<Spacecraft>> call = myAPIService.getSpacecrafts();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Spacecraft>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Spacecraft>> call, Response<List<Spacecraft>> response) {
            spacecraftList = response.body();
            adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getContext(), spacecraftList);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Spacecraft>> call, Throwable throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

class Spacecraft {
    /*
    INSTANCE FIELDS
     */
    @SerializedName("gambar_info")
    private String gambar_info;

    public Spacecraft(int id_info, String gambar_info) {
        this.gambar_info = gambar_info;
    }

    /*
     *GETTERS AND SETTERS
     */

    public String getImageURL() {
        return gambar_info;
    }
}

interface MyAPIService {

    @GET("connection_image_bps.php")
    Call<List<Spacecraft>> getSpacecrafts();
}

static class RetrofitClientInstance {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://bpskotayogyakarta.000webhostapp.com/";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}

class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;
    private Context context;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context,List<Spacecraft> spacecrafts){
        this.context = context;
        this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return spacecrafts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return spacecrafts.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(view==null)
        {
            view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_gambar_info,viewGroup,false);
        }

        ImageView spacecraftImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        final Spacecraft thisSpacecraft= spacecrafts.get(position);

        if(thisSpacecraft.getImageURL() != null && thisSpacecraft.getImageURL().length()>0)
        {
            Picasso.get().load(thisSpacecraft.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(spacecraftImageView);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Empty Image URL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.placeholder).into(spacecraftImageView);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

When I try to run and open that fragment, it results in crash and error

```
2020-01-02 15:26:12.401 2455-2455/com.example.bpskotayogyakarta A/zygote: thread.cc:2090] No pending exception expected: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6
2020-01-02 15:26:12.491 2455-2455/com.example.bpskotayogyakarta A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2455 (skotayogyakarta), pid 2455 (skotayogyakarta)
```

And the rest of the debug https://justpaste.it/2rv1v

And the API PHP file https://justpaste.it/4pdp8

I've been trying over and over, searching on google but I still don't understand. What should I do?

Comment: Can you also post your cloud response which are you storing in `space craft list`?

Comment: @Kushal https://bpskotayogyakarta.000webhostapp.com/connection_image_bps.php

Comment: Error is pretty straight forward, you are trying to access position 6 in a list that only has elements until position 5. Debug your code and find out where. Also the staketrace you posted is limited and it does not tell us where the error is occurring

Comment: @Ricardo this is the rest of the debug https://justpaste.it/2rv1v

Comment: @chrisrobet : Can you post `GsonConvertroFactory` class ? I suspect some problem there

Comment: @Kushal php file for json https://justpaste.it/4pdp8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution by change layout from relative to cardview and adding compabilityOption in build.gradle.

```
compileOptions{
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass null in getItem() and 0 in getItemId()

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We can't pass `null` in `getItem()`. This method would get called when user scrolls down, and based on return value of `getItem()`, new rows would get added

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in GridViewAdapter in the following way:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

The above should solve your problem. 
Also, on your onViewCreated method, why are you using getView()? When view is already called in your constructor as View view. 
You could use `gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);` instead. I guess that is a better way of coding.